# How can I determine the type of another property of same object according to the property's value of the object?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the types as follows:

```
type Operators =
    | "eq"
    | "ne"
    | "lt"
    | "gt"
    | "lte"
    | "gte"
    | "in"
    | "nin"
    | "contains"
    | "ncontains"
    | "containss"
    | "ncontainss"
    | "between"
    | "nbetween"
    | "null"
    | "nnull"
    | "or"

type Filter = {
    field: string;
    operator: Operators;
    value: any
};

export type Filters = Filter[];
```

What I am trying to do is define the `Filter` type by the `Operators` type.

If the user specifies `Operators` as `"or"` then the `field` property is not required and the `value` property is `Filters` type. As follows:

```
export type Filter = {
    field: string | undefined;
    operator: Operators;
    value: Filters;
};
```

If the user specifies `Operators` other than `"or"` then the `field` property is required and the `value` property is `any` type. As follows:

```
export type Filter = {
    field: string;
    operator: Operators;
    value: any
};
```

How can I determine the type of another property of same object according to the property's value of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the `Filters` type as Union type array to switch between your type conditions.

```
/** Separating the operators type into two; not fully needed but easier to understand imo **/

type LogicalOperators = 
    | "eq"
    | "ne"
    | "lt"
    | "gt"
    | "lte"
    | "gte"
    | "in"
    | "nin"
    | "contains"
    | "ncontains"
    | "containss"
    | "ncontainss"
    | "between"
    | "nbetween"
    | "null"
    | "nnull";


type ConditionalOperators = "or" | "and";

/** Intersect these two type, so you can reference it easier later. **/
type Operators = LogicalOperators & ConditionalOperators;

/** Checking the value by the operator and field **/
type LogicalFilter = {
    field: string;
    operator: LogicalOperators;
    value: any
};

/** Combining filters with `or` or `and` **/
type ConditionalFilter = {
    operator: ConditionalOperators;
    value: Filters;
}

/** Define the Filters type as a union **/
type Filters = (LogicalFilter | ConditionalFilter)[];
```

So when you can use `Filters` type like this;

```
const isApple: Filters = [{ field: "fruitName", operator: "eq", value: "Apple" }];

const isAppleOrPear: Filters = [{ operator: "or", value: [{ field: "fruitName", operator: "eq", value: "Apple" }, { field: "fruitName", operator: "eq", value: "Pear" }] }];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Enums you can make field required if the Operator equals Or.

```
enum Operators {
  Eq = "eq",
  Ne = "ne",
  Or = "or"
}

type Filter = {
    field: string;
    operator: Operators.Or;
    value: any
} | type Filter = {
    field: string;
    operator: Operators.Or;
    value: any
} | {
    field?: string;
    operator: Exclude<Operators, Operators.Or>
    value: any
};

// field is required
const filterOr: Filter = {
    field: 'field', 
    value: 'string',
    operator: Operators.Or
}

// field is not required
const filterEq: Filter = {
    value: 'string',
    operator: Operators.Eq
}

const filterEe: Filter = {
    value: 'string',
    operator: Operators.Ne
}
```